# Admob shows Test ads in android studio but no ads at all in google play

Tags: java, android, admob

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hightimes.fourtwenty">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="4:20"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

java

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,"@string/banner_app_id");

mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.myAdView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

.build();


mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

layout file

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/myAdView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    />
```

Gradle script file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The test ad loads fine using android studio, the live google play ad is not showing at all on different test devices and locations. I linked the ad inside the admob app management page and it shows as 1 Active ad. I am using the admob generated appID and adunitID and I also included the google-services.json file.The only thing I could think of is that it either takes a few days for the ads to populate or that my app displays drug related material and it has +18 ratings, but I never received a notice from admob nor do I see anything like account suspended. Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: Get the log whenever the admob hit for advt.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to android..which log are you speaking of.

Comment: Generate a signed apk then install in phone and you'll see the ads.

Comment: Ali, the signed apk is live on google play without an ad, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> MobileAds.initialize(this,"@string/banner_app_id");

You are passing the string "@string/banner_app_id" as the Application ID.

> To find the application ID corresponding to your application, click the App management option under the settings drop-down (located in the upper right hand corner) on the AdMob account page. Application IDs have the form ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~NNNNNNNNNN.

Comment: Thanks Dean, but I think I am using the correct id's or am I missing something?


       <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-ca-app-pub-111111111111111111/00000000000</string>
        <string name="banner_app_id">ca-app-pub-1111111111111111111~00000000000</string>

Comment: Try this if it works: MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.banner_app_id));